# After change my status view is not update before reload my page in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am new in angular my view is not updated automatically whenever I changed my view but view is not updated before I reload my whole page or hit my api call then my view is updated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Share the code Piyush

Answer (score 0):

You are updating a nested object and it is passed as an input to a child component?
In that case, the child component doesn't recognize the property as updated.
Each time you update the property, you need to assign as newly:

```
this.updatingProperty = Object.assign({}, this.updatingProperty);
```